# How to make enemy speed up in the beginning to chase player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making this gravity runner game and i want my enemy to follow my player. The problem I have is that I want my enemy to start outside of the screen so he has to speed up for like 2 seconds to get close to the player. I'm making the game with Unity in C#. How do I do this? This is the code I have so my enemy follows my player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public int MoveSpeed = 18;
    public int MaxDist = 2;
    public int MinDist = 0;
    private Zwaartekracht vijand;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.LookAt(target);

        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position) >= MinDist){

            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;



            if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position) <= MaxDist)
            {
                //Here Call any function U want Like Shoot at here or something

            } 

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to define the distance where enemy is supposed to speed up. Something along the lines of:

```
// Enemy will speed up if he's further away than this
float speedupDistance = 3.0f;

// Distance to smooth out deceleration for speed up
float speedupTransition = 2.0f;

void Update() {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
    float speedup = Mathf.Clamp01((distance - speedupDistance) / speedupTransition);
    float enemySpeed = usualSpeed + maximumOfAditionalSpeed * speedup;
}
```

So when distance is <= 3 you get:

```
speedup = clamp((3 - 3) / 2) = 0
```

When distance is >= 5 you get:

```
speedup = clamp((5 - 3) / 2) = 1
```

When distance goes from 5 to 3, then speedup goes from 1 to 0. So `speedup` will transition from 1 to 0 when enemy is closing in to the player, and you can easily use it to affect enemy's speed.